# How to know which querySelectorAll item got clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code structure:

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

items.forEach(addEventListener (
    'click', function () {
        // code that will get item that got clicked
    }
))
```

Item's HTML looks like this:

```
   <div class="item" data-value="water">water</div>
   <div class="item" data-value="air">air</div>
   <div class="item" data-value="fire">fire</div>
```

And I want to have function that when you click on any item, item's `datavalue` attribute must show in console or anywhere. I just must know which element got clicked.

I tried this

```
items.forEach(addEventListener (
    'click', function () {
        console.log(this.getAttribute('data-value'))
    }
))
```

But it didn't work..

Comment: `items.forEach(addEventListener (` -> `items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener (` [Demo](https://jsbin.com/ruraxil/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

Try like following:

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
items.forEach(item =>
  item.addEventListener (
    'click', function () {
        console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-value'))
    }
))
```

```html
<div class="item" data-value="water">water</div>
   <div class="item" data-value="air">air</div>
   <div class="item" data-value="fire">fire</div>
```